# Best alternative to SQL Server Filestream on Azure SQL service

Tags: sql-server, azure

What is the best alternative to Filestream BLOB data when moving to Azure SQL?

We are planning to move our local SQL Sever database to Azure SQL service. But we are using Filestream to store all our file attachments (which is not supported in Azure SQL). Is there any recommendations from Microsoft on this considering the performance, referential integrity and backups of BLOB data?

Do we have to go back to the old method of storing files on the file system and providing the url on the table? Any idea whether Filestream option will be available in a later releases of Azure SQL, or is this getting moved out?

Appreciate your valuable responses, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome Jacob. Filestream is not supported on Azure SQL Database, because of its nature PaaS. So, in case you do not want to change anything in your SQL Databases, you can consider to use Azure SQL Managed Instance. If you are using your filestream to just query your data, you can use the varbinary type instead of filestream on your table's columns. To migrate your SQL Databases to Azure SQL Managed Instance, please have a look to [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/migrate-your-databases-to-a-fully-managed-service-with-azure-sql-database-managed-instance/).

Comment: Thanks, Hugo. We have DML calls also to filestream data and I have read that this is not supported even on Managed Instance. Varbinary is an option, but whether it impact performance? We are using scan documents extensively in our application.

Comment: According to this document ([When to Use FILESTREAM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)), i assume your documents are bigger than 1MB, so yes you should use Filestream instead of varbinary(max)

Comment: And i am sorry to mislead you in my initial answer, actually looking to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-features) comparing the features of SQL Database and Managed Instance, it does not support Filestream. Since you are migrating to Azure, would you consider to store those documents in Storage Account, and store references in your SQL Database? Storage Account provides you mechanisms to encrypt and secure your documents. And it should not have any issues to scan the documents from there.

Comment: I presume that Storage requires me to manage data integrity and backups separately. Hope some automation between sqlserver and blob storage will come sooner.

Comment: You can leverage [azure storage redundancy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy) to have backups of your data. In terms of data integrity, you can leverage Azure automation to ensure your data integrity. With this approach you will manage things differently but potentially you will end-up with a better solution for your applications, i would say.

Comment: @HugoBarona, have you tried FileStream in a SQL managed instance? I am just confused with the answer provided by "batpox" below. Could you please advise?

Comment: @KushanRandima I did not use FileStream in Azure SQLMI. I just based my reply on the documentation. Storing filestream data in Azure SQLMI has some limitations indeed (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server#filestream-and-filetable). So you can store that data as VARBINARY(MAX) but it will increase the size of your database, or you can store those files externally (e.g. Azure Blob Storage) and store the URL, path and other info for each file in the database. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes - increased size would be an issue as some of our customer DBs are over 120 GB. :-D. 
Using Azure Blob Storage from the same tech stack is a brilliant idea. However, that approach will make the DB restoration meaningless in my business case. Anyway, I need to do a bit of research to accomplish that.

Answer (score 2):

Hugo has the correct answer, but it is in his comment to his acknowledged misleading solution. So I'll reiterate and amplify: Azure SQL Managed Instance simply does not have an alternative to FILESTREAM and I would speculate that most developers that went the FILESTREAM route had already evaluated and discarded the varbinary option. So, you are left to develop your own, perhaps by using files in a Storage Account as mentioned. The downside is that efficiencies of blob operations and features such as automatic backup with SQL backup will be missing. The upside is that your solution may more easily adapt to other cloud services such as AWS.